# Why doesn't TypeScript check the type of this dictionary key?

Tags: typescript

I created a dictionary following the existing answer. But it seems that the compiler checks for the type of value, but not the key. I can use `111` as the key when the key type is string (third assignment). How is this so? Shouldn't the third assignment also cause an error?

```
var dic: { [name: string]: string } = {};

dic["aaa"]=111;
dic["bbb"] = "111";
dic[111] = "111";
```

output

```
test.ts:3:1 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

3 dic["aaa"]=111;
  ~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error.
```

[image]

Comment: number is automatically converted to string when it serves as key.

Comment: Presumably the reason TypeScript doesn't complain about `dic[111] = "111"` is because there's nothing wrong with doing so at runtime. The bracket operator in JS implicitly invokes `ToPropertyKey` on the supplied key, which converts it to a string.

Comment: Only string keys exist in JS. `const a = { }; a[1] = 2; a['1'] = 3; console.log(a); // {1: 3}` That's why it doesn't make sense to differentiate them in TS either.